# Datepicker mobile - settings vs theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker

We are using jquery datepicker for mobile: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/datepicker/
we set the options like this:

```
$('#MyDatePicker').datepicker({
    theme: a,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    firstDay: 1,
});
```

The settings work when we remove the "theme: a"
But then the datepicker has no style and the next and previous button does not appear.
Is this a bug? How can we use the theme and change the settings?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. The right way of changing the settings is:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    firstDay: 1,
});
```

The style is preserved.

Comment: If you are satisfied with this (your) answer accept it (you can do it for your own questions) so others can see it as working solution.  PS. Congrats on solved problem